# Returning value within function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have the following function:

```
const findUserByEmail = (email) => {
  var user
  MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    const dbo = db.db('users')
    dbo.collection('users').findOne({email: email}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err
      else return result
    })
    db.close()
  }).then((user) => {
    return user
  })
}
```

I am trying to return the value of user so that `findUserByEmail(email)`=user but can't figure out how. I have tried using async/await and promises to return this value to get around Node's asynchronous nature however in each I could not get the value to return to the main function. In this case, return user returns the user to the then() function, which is not correct.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very close but there is one thing your missing with your function `findUserByEmail` it needs to return a `Promise`. With a `Promise` you can call `resolve` in the future with the result from `findOne`. This will also change how you consume the `findUserByEmail` function.

**Example**

```
const findUserByEmail = (email) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(url, (mongoError, db) => {
            if (mongoError) {
                return reject(mongoError)
            }

            const dbo = db.db('users')

            dbo.collection('users').findOne({ email: email }, (findError, user) => {
                if (findError) {
                    return reject(findError)
                }

                db.close();

                return resolve(user)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

To consume this function you can use `Promise.then(user => )` or the preferred approach of using `async/await`.

**Consuming using `.then()`**

```
findUserByEmail("email.com").then(user => {
    // do something
}).catch(err => {
    // do something
})
```

**Consuming using `async/await`**

```
async function test() {
    try {
        const user = await findUserByEmail("email.com");
        // do something
    } catch (error) {
        // do something
    }
}
```